# std::exception not being caught?

Tags: c++, exception

This call to glewInit() is failing (which for the record I don't have an answer for either but....) and it throws the exception.

Unfortunately it's not being caught by any of my catchs, not even (...).

What am I doing wrong?

```
try {

   // Initialize GLEW
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        throw std::exception("Failed to initialize GLEW\n");


} catch ( std::system_error const& err) {
    fprintf(stdout, "System Error: %s", err.what());
    glfwTerminate(); // Free glfw if it has been allocated
    // Try Again
    this->InitWithSize(_width, _height);
} catch( std::exception const& err) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Exception Found: %s", err.what());
} catch ( ... ) {
    fprintf(stdout,"Unknown Exception Occured\n");
}
```

Comment: Is this Visual Studio by any chance?  The *exception handling mode* might be at fault here.  Look at [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207464/Exception-Handling-in-Visual-Cplusplus) for more information.

Comment: Try without const in catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "What am I doing wrong?"

Well, concerning the non-appearance of the alleged exception, I frame no hypotheses.

But here are some things you're doing wrong:

- Passing a string to `std::exception` constructor. That's a non-standard extension; [`std::exception`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/exception) doesn't have a constructor that takes a string argument. If you want to pass an exception text, use `std::runtime_error`.
- Not having a normal statement after the possible throwing means you can't be sure that the exception is thrown.
- Having a newline in the exception message. Very problematic convention. Exceptions from other sources won't have that final newline.
- Reporting errors on `stdout`. Use `stderr` for this. That's what it's for.
- Freeing resources in `catch` clauses. Causes wild mayhem, in general. Don't, use destructors for that.

Comment: The error was an anomaly. It was breakpointing the throw everytime even if the code didn't take it there...You did however technically answer part of my question.

Comment: Another candidate, not in this code but in the more general "why isn't my exception caught" case, is `throw new some_exception` and catching with `catch (some_exception &exc)`. Don't heap-allocate the exception.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know it isn't caught?

I'd guess that it is actually caught by `catch( std::exception const& err)` clause. But you forgot to add `\n` at the end of the printed  string, for which reason it doesn't immediately appear on a line-buffered output device. All other `fprintf`s in your code have that `\n`, yet this specific one doesn't.

Either add the `\n` or output to `stderr`.

You probably intended this `fprintf` to eventually look as

```
fprintf(stdout, "Exception Found: %s", err.what());
```

meaning that the `\n` inside the exception text should serve as the terminating `\n`. If so, then do it this way. But what you have currently will not immediately appear on the screen, leading you to believe that the exception was not caught.

Comment: I'm breakpointing to see if it is caught, is it not possible to breakpoint an exception? Thx for the tip about outputting the error.

Comment: I've just confirmed It's still not printing.

Comment: @Josh Elias: I'm out of ideas. Does your compiler by any chance have some sort of setting, like "Enable C++ exceptions" or something like that?

Comment: Worth noting that the OP changed the code after this answer was posted.